# Laravel query subquery

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

For example I have 2 queries:

**1:**

```
$q = SomeContent::select('somecontent_id')
    ->where('slug', Request::segment(2))
    ->where('something', $something)
    ->first();
```

**2**

```
$req = SomeContent::select('slug')
    ->where('something', $anothersomething)
    ->where('somecontent_id', $q->somecontent_id)
    ->first();
```

How would I merge these together as one query if possible in laravel's query builder? I can't find a lot about using selects statements inside where statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can [union](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) them together, something like

```
// The query builder also provides a quick way to "union" two queries together:

$q = SomeContent::select('somecontent_id')
    ->where('slug', Request::segment(2))
    ->where('something', $something);

$req = SomeContent::select('slug')
    ->where('something', $anothersomething)
    ->where('somecontent_id', $q->somecontent_id)
    ->union($q)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also you the orWhere function

```
$q = SomeContent::select('somecontent_id')
      ->where('slug', Request::segment(2))
       ->where('something', $something)
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('something', $anothersomething)
          ->where('somecontent_id', $q->somecontent_id)
           ->union($q)->get();
        })
        ->get();
```